# repair incomplete .git directory

Tags: git

I have a working directory that is a git repository. Today, I changed a lot in the folder and file structure and also moved the `.git` directory around a bit. Now, trying to commit those changes, I am getting the following error:

```
fatal: Not a git repository (or any parent up to mount parent )
```

I googled the error, and found the criteria git uses to determine if the current directory is a git repository. It turns out, my `.git` is missing some files and folders:

```
$ ls -la .git
total 36
drwxr-xr-x   5 oli oli 4096 Apr  6 10:51 .
drwxr-xr-x  10 oli oli 4096 Apr  6 11:05 ..
-rw-r-xr--   1 oli oli   30 Mar  3 13:39 COMMIT_EDITMSG
-rw-r--r--   1 oli oli   41 Mar  3 13:40 ORIG_HEAD
-rw-r--r--   1 oli oli 6612 Mar  3 13:40 index
drwxr-xr-x   2 oli oli 4096 Jan 27 19:58 info
drwxr-xr-x   3 oli oli 4096 Jan 27 19:58 logs
drwxr-xr-x 165 oli oli 4096 Mar  3 13:40 objects
```

Compared to another repository, there are multiple objects missing, most importantly the `HEAD` file. I don't exactly know, how they got lost (I always moved the whole directory) but the question is now, how to restore everything so that I still have the commit log and can commit my changes to the repository.

Answer (score 2):

No idea whether this will work, but try this (after making backups). I hope files from `.git/objects` were not lost - otherwise I doubt anything would help.

1. Create an empty repository with `git init`
2. Copy your incomplete repository on top of it, overwriting any files that the empty repository also had.

If it's now recognized as a Git repository but some commits are missing, do this:

1. `git fsck --lost-found`
2. Move the `.git/lost-found/commit` directory under `.git/refs/heads`
3. Check the history with `gitk --all` and create branches or tags for anything you want to save.
4. Finally clean up: push the saved branches to a remote repository or remove from `.git/refs/heads` the lost and found branches.

Then next time remember to make backups, either by pushing to a remote repository or by using an automatic backup application. ;)

Comment: Thanks for the help. I managed to restore it from the remote repo by cloning it into a different folder and copied the missing files to my repo. committing worked then and now everything fine.